# Can you deactivate 2 player mode when Switch is moved while also using synced controller?

Tags: nintendo-switch-lite

Does anyone know how I can stop Switch from entering 2 player mode? My son has autism and I got him the Switch lite for Christmas. Before I give it to him I like to make sure I know how to use it to show him.

I have a remote control I sync to the Switch and whenever the Switch is moved it goes into 2 player mode. This will drive him crazy cause I can’t explain to him not to move the Switch. So, is there a way to deactivate 2 player mode from coming on even if the Switch is moved?

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand about the question: What is that remote control you're talking about? Why do you need it? Why would the Switch Lite switch into 2 player mode, when it's inherently a single-player portable console that was designed for moving around? I understand why it's driving your son crazy, because the situation doesn't really make any sense to me either.

Comment: Is this happening with a specific game?